# Getting netInstall to work over two sunbnets connected by IPSEC

Tags: pfsense, apple, netinstall

I would like to know if anyone has tried to get BDSP packets to travel across subnets connected over an IPSEC VPN using a pair of Pfsense boxes?

My goal is to be able to netRestore macbooks from our HQ to our remote offices, the setup looks like this:

```
[macServer]<--10.0.10.0--->[SITE HQ]<----IPSEC--->[SITE A]<--10.0.20.0-->[MACBOOK]
```

Thanks for any insight...